# setInterval() Не работает при переключении вкладки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

```
var a= 0;
setInterval(function() {
    document.write(a);
    a++;
}, 5000)
```

Если я переключаюсь и на вкладке было `10` то при возвращении там все равно `10`. Kак сделать, чтобы работал даже если я переключился на другую вкладку?

Comment: Явно нельзя, но никто не запрещает использовать объект Date() внутри функции, вызывающейся по интервалу, чтобы смотреть сколько реально прошло времени, а не с момента переключения

Comment: СОбственно соль в том что там загрузка игры. И, когда я переключаю вкладку она стопориться, а при возвращений продолжается

Comment: Имхо, поднимитесь на уровень выше и сформулируйте задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить вот таким методом. Возможно для этой задачи есть решение лучше чем `document.write` в интервале

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` крайне не рекомендуется использовать, потому что функция реально доступна только при загрузке файла, при этом останавливает обработку последующего кода. Ваш код у меня в Firefox вообще не работал.

Лучше воспользуйтесь DOM:

```js
var a = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a + " "));
  a++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Вот у вас даже если  переключить вкладку он продолжает работать, а у меня нет.

Comment: @СлаваГесто Ваша версия вообще не должна работать (и не работает в некоторых браузерах). Вам что-то мешает использовать мою версию?

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые браузеры (напр. Safari, Chrome), приостанавливают JS-таймеры или замедляют их выполнение при работе в фоне. Можете проверить это используя функцию requestAnimationFrame вместо setInterval.